# Django: queryset - get a specfic column from DB in plain text

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to list out names of associations from database in plain text but what i get is this:

https://gyazo.com/6588724ee73431e10e88bcfa3650f99d

How can I exclude parenthesis, comma and ticks?

Still a newbie so appreciate your help!

Forms.py

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    association = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Association.objects.values_list("asoc_name"),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    required=True)
```

Models.py

```
class Association(models.Model):
   ...
   asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)   

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Association'
```

Comment: you probably meant to indent the Meta-class, so that it is inside the Association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

('Dortmund',) is clearly the repr of a tuple. From the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

> It returns tuples when iterated over. Each tuple contains the value
>   from the respective field passed into the values_list() call

So you could do a list comprehension on it but actually there is a better solution if you look at the next paragraph in the doc :

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat
>   parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single
>   values, rather than one-tuples

So

```
queryset=Association.objects.values_list("asoc_name", flat=True)
```

should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method to get the strings of type `city_name = "('Dortmund'),"` - then you can remove the extra characters by name_plain = city_name.split("'")[1].

Maybe you should add a `__str__(self)`-method to your Association-class in which you `return name_plain` at the end.

Sorry I can't be more specific, since I don't understand where the extra characters come from, if they are in the DB or something else...